# save android WebView cache and load no internet

Tags: android, caching, webview, load

I search and no find any learn for my questions please help.

my `WebView` code :

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
initWebView(webView);

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);   
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/cache/");  
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the exact error that you get or the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if(connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()){
  mfnWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
  mfnWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
else{
  mfnWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
  mfnWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Mandatory permissions :- INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

Comment: CACHE modes are added from API level 1. It should work. Can you tell me OS & Device details.